# SQL Selecting Repetead Rows in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I am currently refreshing my SQL knowledge.

I have a table - Sessions. It stores information about user log activity. ie the duration of how long they are logged in for. See the table below.

[image]

So I am trying to select all repeated rows from a table (not just validate that repeated rows exist).
So far I have managed to get the output of the entire table, however, I only need the userId and duration columns. How can I go about selecting only these two rows?

I thought it would have been SELECT a.userId instead of a.* etc however I get the error "ambiguous column name: userId". Not sure what is going on. Sorry if it's a stupid question but any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
  SELECT a.*                      
  FROM sessions a
  JOIN ( SELECT userId,duration
          FROM sessions 
          GROUP BY userId
          HAVING COUNT(userId) > 1 ) b
    ON a.userId = b.userId
    ORDER BY userId;
```

[image]

Comment: For next time, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the `ORDER BY` clause, which does not scope the `userId` reference to one of the tables.  Use this version:

```
ORDER BY a.userId;
```

Here is your updated query, with the select clause of the subquery also corrected by removing the incorrect (and unnecessary) reference to `duration`:

```
SELECT a.*                      
FROM sessions a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT userId
    FROM sessions 
    GROUP BY userId
    HAVING COUNT(userId) > 1
) b
    ON a.userId = b.userId
ORDER BY
    a.userId;
```